# Как работает итератор хэш-таблицы?

Tags: java, итераторы, java-hashmap

Здравствуйте, уважаемые коллеги, у меня задание создать справочник по образу `HashMap`, и когда я начал делать методы для добавления, вставки, и тому подобное, то столкнулся с проблемой: мне нужен итератор, который будет сначала смотреть на ячейку, потом проходить по связанному списку в ней и переходить к следующей, и не понимаю как мне его сделать. Понятно что это должно быть что-то вроде итератора итераторов, и я даже делал такое задание, но то были итераторы на массивах, а тут у меня внешний уровень массив, а внутренний связные списки, и я в тупике.

Как мне сделать такой итератор в данном контексте? Буду безумно благодарен за любую помощь, советом или кодом...

Вот код самого справочника:

```
public class ReferenceBook<K, V> implements Book<K, V> {
    private Node<K, V>[] hashTable;
    private final float DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR = 0.75f;
    private float threshold = hashTable.length * DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR;
    private int size = 0;

    ReferenceBook() {
        hashTable = new Node[16];
    }

    @Override
    public boolean insert(K key, V value) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean delete(K key) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public V get(K key) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<V> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<V>() {
            int countArray = 0;
            // Вот тут корень моих проблем. Подскажите что я могу предпринять чтобы итератор работал как надо?
            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return currentCellOfTableHaveMoreElement() || arrayTableHaveMoreCell();
            }

            private boolean arrayTableHaveMoreCell() {
                return countArray < hashTable.length;
            }

            private boolean currentCellOfTableHaveMoreElement() {
                return hashTable[countArray].getNext().getValue() != null;
            }

            @Override
            public V next() {
                return null;
            }

        };
    }


    private class Node<K, V> {
        private Node<K, V> next;
        private int hash;
        private K key;
        private V value;

        Node(K key, V value, Node<K, V> next) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
            this.next = next;
            initHash();
        }

        private void initHash() {
            hash = 31;
            hash = hash * 17 + key.hashCode();
            hash = hash * 17 + next.hashCode();
            hash = hash * 17 + value.hashCode();
        }

        public Node<K, V> getNext() {
            return next;
        }

        public K getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        public V getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return hash;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;

            if (obj instanceof Node<?, ?>) {
                Node<K, V> node = (Node) obj;
                return (Objects.equals(key, node.getKey()) &&
                        Objects.equals(value, node.getValue()) ||
                        Objects.equals(hash, node.hashCode()));
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: зачем вам нужен итератор итераторов? какие ограничения наложены на итератор?

Comment: Вообще не по теме, но у вас какая-то беда с хэшкодом в Node. Там будет NPE при обращении к next (потому что вам так или иначе необходимо создать первый Node), а value имеет право поменяться. И должен ли вообще меняться хэшкод Node при появлении next или изменении value?

Comment: @etki да там есть проблемы я еще просто не дошел до этого.

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman про итератор итераторов это только предположение, главное придумать как мне проходить по хэш-таблице по принципу: берем первую ячейку проходим по всему списку потом вторую проходим по всему списку и так далее...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самую примитивную реализацию прохода по всем элементам `HashMap` можно сделать **примерно** так:

```
for (int i=0; i<hashTable.length; i++) {
    if (hashTable[i] != null) {
        Node<K, V> node = hashTable[i];
        do {
            System.out.println(node.getValue());
            node = node.getNext();
        } while (node != null);
    }
}
```

Но данный подход неоптимален, так как просматриваются все элементы массива. Его можно усовершенствовать, используя значение `size`:

```
int count = 0;
for (int i=0; count != size; i++) {
    if (hashTable[i] != null) {
        MyNode<K, V> node = hashTable[i];
        do {
            System.out.println(node.getValue());
            count++;
            node = node.getNext();
        } while (node != null);
    }
}
```

В этом варианте `HashMap` просматривается до тех пор, пока в нем есть элементы.

А итератор можно **примерно** так реализовать:

```
public Iterator<V> iterator() {
    return new Iterator<V>() {
        int currentNodeNumber = 0;
        int currentArrayIndex = 0;
        Node<K, V> currentNode;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return currentNodeNumber < size;
        }

        @Override
        public V next() {
            for (; currentNodeNumber != size; currentArrayIndex++) {
                if (hashTable[currentArrayIndex] != null) {
                    if (currentNode == null) {
                        currentNode = hashTable[currentArrayIndex];
                    }

                    currentNodeNumber++;
                    V value = currentNode.getValue();
                    currentNode = currentNode.getNext();
                    if (currentNode == null) {
                        currentArrayIndex++;
                    }
                    return value;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: И снова здравствуйте)) , спасибо за ваш ответ, но у меня 2 вопроса: 1. в хэш таблице же индекс при добавлении рассчитывается из int index = hash(key) % hashTable.length как же мы можем идти по таблице просто итерируясь если в массиве будет дыра null то мы не узнаем что будет дальше. 2. а если у нас коллизия решается через добавление в ту-же ячейку, в связный список? То элементы которые попали вторыми в ячейку мы не увидим? Или я что-то не так понимаю? Я имею в виду первые 2 куска кода.

Comment: @Павел, 1. Если в какой-то корзине находится `null`, то это значит, что в этой корзине ничего нет, следовательно, можно переходить к следующей корзине. 2. Да, случай коллизий решается именно так. Увидим. Я этот код писал не на коленке, а проверял. Попробуйте пройтись отладчиком по коду, возможно, алгоритм работы станет яснее.

Comment: >>>Я этот код писал не на коленке, а проверял<<< я даже не думал на это намекать, просто спросил...